# Join if a string is included in other string

Tags: r

I have two sets data frame like this and I would like to join them by their string

```
> part <- data.frame(name = c("I", "want", "to", "go", "there", "you", "are", "seeing"),
+                    value = c(0.77, 0.55, 0.33, 0.4, 0.5, 0.9, 1.0, 0.91))
> full <- data.frame(sentence = c("I want to go there", "you are seeing"))
```

How can I join them based on where name in sentence is exist? Like this

```
    name value           sentence
1      I  0.77 I want to go there
2   want  0.55 I want to go there
3     to  0.33 I want to go there
4     go  0.40 I want to go there
5  there  0.50 I want to go there
6    you  0.90     you are seeing
7    are  1.00     you are seeing
8 seeing  0.91     you are seeing
```

Comment: I think you are going to need a column in your data frame which demarcates where one sentence ends and another begins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with

```
sapply(part$name, function(x) {grepl(full[1,1],pattern = x)})
```

And work from there:

working but maybe not efficient example:

```
lst <- sapply(full$sentence,function(y){
which(sapply(part$name, function(x) {grepl(y,pattern = x)}))
})


lst2 <- lapply(seq_along(lst),function(x)  
{data.frame(full=rep(full[x,1],length(lst[[x]])),part=part[lst[[x]],1])})

do.call(rbind, lst2)
```